# Visualize Multilevel Growth Model with nlme/ggplot2 vs lme4/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, nlme

I am trying to visualize the results of an `nlme` object without success. When I do so with an `lmer` object, the correct plot is created. My goal is to use `nlme` and visualize a fitted growth curve for each individual with `ggplot2`. The `predict()` function seems to work differently with `nlme` and `lmer` objects.

model:

```
#AR1 with REML
autoregressive <- lme(NPI ~ time,
                  data = data,
                  random = ~time|patient,
                  method = "REML",
                  na.action = "na.omit",
                  control = list(maxlter=5000, opt="optim"),
                  correlation = corAR1())
```

`nlme` visualization attempt:

```
data <- na.omit(data)

data$patient <- factor(data$patient,
                   levels = 1:23)

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=NPI, colour=factor(patient))) +
    geom_point(size=1) +
    #facet_wrap(~patient) +
    geom_line(aes(y = predict(autoregressive,
                              level = 1)), size = 1)
```

[image: incorrect visualization]

when I use:

```
data$fit<-fitted(autoregressive, level = 1) 
geom_line(aes(y = fitted(autoregressive), group = patient))
```

it returns the same fitted values for each individual and so ggplot produces the same growth curve for each. Running `test <-data.frame(ranef(autoregressive, level=1))` returns varying intercepts and slopes by patient id. Interestingly, when I fit the model with `lmer` and run the below code it returns the correct plot. **Why does `predict()` work differently with `nlme` and `lmer` objects?**

```
timeREML <- lmer(NPI ~ time + (time | patient), 
                 data = data,
                 REML=T, na.action=na.omit)

ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = NPI, colour = factor(patient))) +
    geom_point(size=3) +
    #facet_wrap(~patient) +
    geom_line(aes(y = predict(timeREML)))
```

[image: correct plot]

Comment: By "visualize the random effects estimated by the model" do you mean plot the fitted growth curve for each individual? I think you could change `geom_line(aes(y = fitted(autoregressive), group = id))` or start by adding `data$fit<-fitted(autoregressive)`

Comment: Thank you for responding @Niek. I tried using `fitted()` but it is returning the same fitted values for each individual. I updated my question above. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? Without your data I cannot take a look. Try to reproduce the issue with randomly generated data or a public data set.

Answer (score 0):

In creating a reproducible example, I found that the error was not occurring in `predict()` nor in `ggplot()` but instead in the `lme` model.

Data:

```
###libraries
library(nlme)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

###example data
df <- data.frame(replicate(78, sample(seq(from = 0, 
            to = 100, by = 2), size = 25, 
            replace = F)))

##add id
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

##rearrange cols
df <- df[c(79, 1:78)]

##sort columns
df[,2:79] <- lapply(df[,2:79], sort)

##long format
df <- gather(df, time, value, 2:79)

##convert time to numeric
df$time <- factor(df$time)
df$time <- as.numeric(df$time)

##order by id, time, value
df <- df[order(df$id, df$time),]

##order value
df$value <- sort(df$value)
```

Model 1 with no NA values fits successfully.

```
###model1
model1 <- lme(value ~ time,
                  data = df,
                  random = ~time|id,
                  method = "ML",
                  na.action = "na.omit",
                  control = list(maxlter=5000, opt="optim"),
                  correlation = corAR1(0, form=~time|id,
                                       fixed=F))
```

Introducing NA's causes invertible coefficient matrix error in model 1.

```
###model 1 with one NA value
df[3,3] <- NA

model1 <- lme(value ~ time,
                  data = df,
                  random = ~time|id,
                  method = "ML",
                  na.action = "na.omit",
                  control = list(maxlter=2000, opt="optim"),
                  correlation = corAR1(0, form=~time|id,
                                       fixed=F))
```

But not in model 2, which has a more simplistic within-group AR(1) correlation structure.

```
###but not in model2
model2 <- lme(value ~ time,
                  data = df,
                  random = ~time|id,
                  method = "ML",
                  na.action = "na.omit",
                  control = list(maxlter=2000, opt="optim"),
                  correlation = corAR1(0, form = ~1 | id))
```

However, changing `opt="optim"` to `opt="nlminb"` fits model 1 successfully.

```
###however changing the opt to "nlminb", model 1 runs 
model3 <- lme(value ~ time,
          data = df,
          random = ~time|id,
          method = "ML",
          na.action = "na.omit",
          control = list(maxlter=2000, opt="nlminb"),
          correlation = corAR1(0, form=~time|id,
                               fixed=F))
```

The code below visualizes model 3 (formerly model 1) successfully.

```
df <- na.omit(df)

ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(id))) +
    #facet_wrap(~id) +
    geom_line(aes(y = predict(model3, level = 0)), size = 1.3, colour = "black") +
    geom_line(aes(y = predict(model3, level=1, group=id), colour = factor(id)), size = 1)
```

Note that I am not exactly sure what changing the optimizer from `"optim"` to `"nlminb"` does and why it works.